# Disable touch for the duration of a block in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, block

I have a deep cloning process in my rails app, as well as a recursive deletion process that deletes the node of a tree and its descendants and their associations. Both of these routines have problems when :touch => true is applied to the relationships. It's fine when we're just updating one record to have the change touch all the parent records up the associations and tree structure, but when we're dealing with bulk creation or deletion it makes sense to disable touching for the duration of that call.

I'm looking for direction around how I'd define a method that accepts a block for running code that would not activate the touch method on objects.

I'm thinking perhaps just before yielding I should set a global? variable that indicates touching is disabled, and then override the touch method to first check for this variable before calling super (or not as the case may be).

Any help to solidify this into actual code would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi! How did you eventually approach this? I'm considering a similar case for testing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922864/how-to-disable-belongs-to-touch-option-in-rspec-tests-for-rails-models

Comment: I never got around this. I just had to accept that updating is very slow and error prone when deleting unless things are done in exactly the right order. Rails 3 is better in that it doesn't try to save the entire model, just update the timestamps in isolation which is much nicer. No such luck for Rails 2 where this project is still stuck! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 4.1 or later you can use the ActiveRecord `no_touching` method to prevent touching in a single model or in all models like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.no_touching do
  Project.first.touch  # does nothing
  Message.first.touch  # does nothing
end

Project.no_touching do
  Project.first.touch  # does nothing
  Message.first.touch  # works, but does not touch the associated project
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could get pretty hairy trying to come up with a way to do this generically. When you declare a `belongs_to` association with the `:touch` option, it create a new method for association you want to touch that handles the touching if the save/update/destroy is successful. If you still want to head forward, take a look at [add_touch_callbacks](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Builder/BelongsTo/add_touch_callbacks), which does this method definition and hooking.

I guess my point of attack would be to identify the associations that are being touched, then override their method definitions with an empty method, yield to the block, then entire the overridden method definitions were put back into place, so touching works again.

Comment: I'll accept this though I never ended up trying this. Am going to raise a question on the rails github issues area about making touch more efficient by only having it update the timestamps and execute only the associated touch callbacks instead of saving the whole object.