# How to disable belongs_to :touch option in Rspec tests for Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, metaprogramming, belongs-to

Having a large model stack and using doll caching techniques extensively, one ends up with lots of parent models been "touched" after a model update.

While testing, this seems to be a time waster unless you try to test that feature specifically.

Is there a way to prevent models to `touch` their `belongs_to` associations for the test environment or at a test level?

UPDATE 1:

My first attempt to the case would be to

```
# /config/initializers/extensions.rb
#
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.without_touch_for_association(association_name, &block)
    association_name = association_name.to_sym
    association = self.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).select { |reflection| reflection.name == association_name }.first
    options = association.options
    association.instance_variable_set :@options, options.except(:touch)

    yield

    association.instance_variable_set :@options, options
  end
end

Post.without_touch_for_association(:user) do
  Post.last.save
end
```

Of course, no success and saving `Post.last` still touches it's `User`.

UPDATING RATIONALE:

I understand and agree that this approach may be a source of bugs and it's not a good practice at all. The thing is that I have a huge suite with lots of both integration and unit tests. Doll caching also gets deep in the model tree. Every time I look at the logs, I see a significant % of touch-related queries. I know the best way would be optimizing the unit tests to add more mocking and stubbing and less persistence. Solving the issue within integration tests is more difficult.

In any case, I'm asking this question for the sake of learning and research. I am interested in exploring the potential speed improvements of this technique.

SOLUTION: see my own answer below for the working code.

Comment: Apologies in advance for not offering a direct solution. However, I would be very wary of attempting this in the first place, as it would significantly alter the behaviour of your application, and become a rich potential source of production-only bugs. If `#touch` calls really are causing a significant slow-down to your test suite, it seems likely that too many persisted records are being created in the first place. Are you concerned primarily with unit tests, or with integration tests?

Comment: Thanks SimonC! I updated the question with my rationale. Cheers!

Comment: Well, i don't think this is a very good suggestion, but can't the touch method be stubbed for any instance like so:
`User.any_instance.stub(:touch).and_return(true)`
 so it does not actually do anything?

Comment: Nope. I refer to ``belongs_to :user, touch: true``, where I want to silence the ``touch`` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Rails >= 4.2**

Thanks to @Dorian, in Rails 4.2 the way to go is using [ActiveRecord::NoTouching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NoTouching/ClassMethods.html).

**For Rails < 4.2**

My working code in rspec support file:

```
# /spec/support/active_record_extensions.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.without_touch_for_association(association, &block)
    method_name = :"belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_#{association}"
    return unless self.instance_methods.include?(method_name)

    method = self.send(:instance_method, method_name)
    self.send(:define_method, method_name) { true }

    yield

    self.send(:define_method, method_name, method)
    nil
  end

  def self.disable_touch_associations!
    associations = self.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)
    associations.each do |association|
      self.without_touch_for_association association.name do
        return
      end
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Add this to your `./spec/spec_helper.rb` to disable all touch calls for any model defined, for the whole test suite:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  if ENV['SILENCE_TOUCHES']
    config.before :suite do
      ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each {|model| model.disable_touch_associations! }
    end
  end
end
```

Temporarely disabling a touch for a model and association in a particular test.

```
Post.without_touch_for_association(:user) do
  Post.last.save
end
```

Thanks to @xlembouras below for pointing me to the right direction!

I'm playing with this feature on our tests and I'm noticing a 25% reduction in test suite speed, for a 30min test suite. I may post more accurate results after more thorough research.

Comment: This is quite different from what I say. You end up monkey-patching your `ActiveRecord::Base` and add extra functionality in your whole stack just for testing. All of this should be extracted either to your factories (prefered) or to a before block in your specs that would be executed only when needed and for specific models.

Comment: Hey! You're right. I actually used the later adding the code to the spec_helper.rb file, controlled by a environment variable. I failed to explain that in the answer, but I just updated it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: By the way, I'd love to use this within my factories, but adding a trait for every factory is not a good approach IMHO. I did not found how to add this bit globally to all the factories.

Comment: @xlembouras I'm curious: why the downvote? I believe this answer is more complete in regards to the solving the question. I could accept yours, but you need to provide the generalization requested. In any case, this answer is correct.

Comment: it wasn't me. I just added the comment.

Comment: Ok then, thanks then whoever made the undownvote :-)

Comment: [ActiveRecord::NoTouching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NoTouching/ClassMethods.html) is the correct way to do it

Comment: @Dorian I added back the old code, since it is still valid for any project with Rails < 4.2

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're on Rails 4.1.4 or newer:

```
User.no_touching do
  Post.last.save
end
```

or even

```
ActiveRecord::Base.no_touching do
  Post.last.save
end
```

See [ActiveRecord::NoTouching](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NoTouching/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the notion of altering the code for test purposes. Testing from my point of view should be an independent procedure.

As I see it you should provide a way to your test suite to alter the behavior of a model only for certain cases.

The following code

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, touch: true
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

which is your case will define an instance method

`belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_author`

behind the scene for the `Book` class.
( thanks to AR http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Builder/BelongsTo/add_touch_callbacks )

So in your test code you could override that method to do something different or nothing at all!

In my case I use Rspec with [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), so what I did was to create a special factory trait for the `Book` class which redefines `belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_author` for that object

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :book do
    ...
    ...
  end

  trait :no_touch do
    before(:create) do |book_no_touch|
      def book_no_touch.belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_author
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That way, when you need to test something where touching the related objects is irrelevant, you can create a book object with that factory

`book = FactoryGirl.create(:book, :no_touch)`

Comment: Yes! I tried this snippet on the console: ``Post.send( :define_method, :belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_user) { true }`` and it succeeded to disable the callback. Now, for the A: any idea on how to generalize this for all AR classes, as I was attempting?

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe by patching FactoryGirl's factory?

Comment: Well, I eventually solved it with your help. I posted my full working solution, and mark it as solved as is the most complete, but the credit and bounty goes to you for pointing me to the belongs_to_touch... method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to work but you could try the following:

```
belongs_to :foo, touch: APP_CONFIG['doll_touch']
```

where APP_CONFIG is an application parameter that is set following this [guide](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file).

So, in your production/development part of the configuration, you set `doll_touch` to `true` and in your test to `false`.

Comment: Hmm it seems this should work. Good try in deed. But this will require changing the original code a few dozen times ... I'd still would like to understand how to monkey patch the test environment, I'm going to wait for someone to answer that part. If none, bounty is yours.

Comment: No worries, I believe you will find a "monkey patched" solution sooner or later.